# Close 8080 for incoming requests on Windows 10

Tags: tomcat, firewall

The development environment for [REST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) development needs a [Web Container](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_container). I am using a locally installed [Apache Tomcat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Tomcat).
That laptop is connected to a huge intranet and should be protected against unwanted access from outside.

What is a good approach for this protection?

I tried configuring the Win10 firewall rules and filtering, e.g. applying **wf.msc**, but without success.

Comment: Does [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/network/introduction-to-windows-filtering-platform-callout-drivers) help you? It's something "similar" to *iptables* on *Windows*. You can create a route that forbids all outside traffic but at the same time allows traffic from inside on one single port.

Comment: @FourBars thanks, it helps. citation: "... extend the capabilities ... beyond ... simple filtering". Let me extend my question: my requirement can not be achieved by *simple filtering*?

Comment: What programming language are you using to code this protection? It looks like you are looking for some Windows solution instead of developing your own one. What does it really have to do with programming?

Comment: @Dharman I am using Python as the client language, Java as the language for the REST service.

Comment: It's fairly simple: With Python I am using the *Requests* module, with Java I am using the *Spring-Boot* eco system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a method by introducing a Tomcat valve added to *%CATALINA_HOME%\conf\server.xml*:

```
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve"
    allow="127\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+|::1|0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1"/>
```

This way the locally installed *Tomcat* can only be accessed locally.

Comment: Notice that the IP6 part of the regex allows for two representations. [Seems to be important for Win10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69786709/why-a-blocking-valve-does-not-work-as-expected-on-win10).