# Why a blocking valve, does not work as expected on Win10?

Tags: tomcat

I am trying to block access to my *REST* development - applying *Tomcat* - from outside of my laptop. The solution I have found promising, is to [introduce a valve for Tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69765425/close-8080-for-incoming-requests-on-windows-10):

```
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve" allow="127\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+|::1"/>
```

It works on Linux: The intention is, that `localhost:8080` accesses the local *Tomcat* installation with the expected, while any access `<my-laptop-IP>:8080` from anywhere on the intranet will be denied.

Unfortunately this works fine on my *Buster* laptop (a Linux *VirtualBox* guest) but neither on my *Win10* guest installation nor on a native *Win10* laptop: That valve on Windows blocks `localhost:8080` access to *Tomcat* as well, although I think, the `allow` attribute shall allow it. (Means my *REST* developent is blocked on Win10 with that valve.)

My question is: **Why does the above valve behaves not as expected on *Win10* installations?**

p.s. I tested with tomcat-9 and tomcat-10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On most modern OS `localhost` resolves to the IPv6 address `::1` first and then to the IPv6 address `127.0.0.1`.

Depending on the connector you are using the IPv6 address for `localhost` may appear in the abbreviated form `::1` or the full form `0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1`, therefore your regular expression should allow both representations:

```xml
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve"
       allow="127\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+|::1|0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1"/>
```